# Videojs can not load the video link

Tags: javascript, c#

In my MVC project, I have an action named GetVideo and its return a base.File("xxxx", "contenttype");

```
  Public ActionResult GetVideo(int id) {
        if (id == 1) {
              return base.File("\\x.x.x.x\1.mp4.", "video/mp4");
        }
        else ........
    }
```

when i use http://localhost:55919/Service/GetVideo?id=1, the video can be retrieved successful. However, when i embed the link into the video tag, the videojs player can not load the video link.

```
     <video id="inspection" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="none" width="800" height="400"
              poster="../images/afcd.gif">
            <source src="http://localhost:55919/Service/GetVideo?id=1" type='video/mp4' />
     </video>
```

In this case, how can i solve this problem?